# DIV background-image overflow

Tags: image, html, background, overflow

I have a DIV element with a background-image, and I want it to overflow outside the dimensions of the DIV (it now cuts off the image because the image is bigger than the DIV).

Is this possible? `overflow:visible` doesn't work!

Comment: the background image is not part of the content of the div, that's the point :) this is why overflow will not help you.

Comment: Sorry but you have been mistaken, as Elad Lachmi sad that the background image is not the part of the div, and I did'nt get your question correctly please give us a link or add it in the jsFiddle so that we can see the problem with our eyes.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in alternative way:

```
#box {
    margin:-50px 0 0;
    padding:50px 0 0 0;
    background:url(/images/image.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put the background on a larger `<div>` that contains your `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible with CSS3. I stumbled on this post while attempting this myself and discovered I could do it.

Here's the code I used:

```css
#page
{
  width:1024px;
  height:662px;
  padding:0 58px 105px 58px;
  background-image:url(../images/milk_splash.png), url(../images/content_back.png);
  background-size: 1082px 767px, 1024px 662px;
  background-origin:padding-box, content-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position:top left, top left;
}
```

Your images will layer down in the order you put them in. Your padding is the offset difference in size from your div.

I discovered this and just had to share it. Will not work in IE <9.