# Large image causing background to disappear

Tags: html, css

I've a similar problem than [div background-image overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530141/div-background-image-overflow) :
I've a page where I want a 'header' and a 'footer' with the same background. 
Immediately under the header, a large image and finally under this image the content.

All the content(incl header/footer/image) is centered and the problem is with the image (width:1600px) and the size of the browser... When it's under 1600px, we can scroll and the background STOPS... I'd like them to be extended as well...
(I can set the body element with the same background than header/footer, but the content would be missing it...)

Here is the a jsFiddle as [an example of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/7brph/), I ended-up having Wraps around the different parts to set the correct backgrounds.

Here is the normal behavior, full sized screen [image: Here is the normal behavior]

Here is the problem, when the the browser is smaller than the content, the scroll-bar appear and the background disappear... [image: Here is the problem]

I tried many many things to find the workaround. I cannot set a min-width:1600px to the bodywrap (to my real case) as it will cause a lot of scroll for a small resolution user to find the 'centered content' !

If you have suggestions, or a different approach to my problem, thanks in advance !

**Final edit** : 
- @Happy Singh code (using a background image and a overflow:hidden on the imagewrap) with my addition of min-width for each content element. [The final jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux2pj/3/).

Comment: this image should be a background image...

Comment: Are you missing some link which you want to show us. Like you mention above - Here is the normal behavior, full sized screen Here is the normal behavior, Here is the problem, when the the browser is smaller....?

Comment: @HappySingh : Can you see the two images (having the title you mention) !?

Comment: @soju : I tried with a background-image instead, and the problem is still there : http://jsfiddle.net/7brph/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3KtSf/ if i am getting your problem correct then it might be your solution;

**UPDATE:**

Revised fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ux2pj/1/ ) as per comment's requirement.

In the fiddle the image is from background so the width/height of image is 500 x 367px.

Comment: The image should have the original width at all time, people with high resolution enjoying it in it's full size and people with lower resolution, just it's middle part. So the stretching is not a solution :( Thanks for your time

Comment: ok it means you want to show the orignal size of the image. no need to reduce/increase the size of image. wait let me try on 1 more solution.

Comment: Please see the updated fiddle. If still i am not getting your problem please let me know. i want to solve this problem.

Comment: Almost, I fixed it there : http://jsfiddle.net/ux2pj/3/ . I applied a min width(400px(content size)) on each wrapper including the large image, this extanding the background when scrolling. You overflow:hidden the imagewrap as well. Nice ! Now I'll have to adapt a jQuery plugin in order for it to work with background-image...